# Request to Google Endpoints Quickstart API Fails with a 503

Tags: google-app-engine, curl, google-cloud-endpoints, google-apis-explorer

I am working through the Quickstart for Cloud Endpoints Frameworks on Google App Engine. After deploying the app I try to send a request to the API as outlined in the Quickstart:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"content":"Hello world!"}' https://[my-app].appspot.com/_ah/api/echo/v1/echo
```

It returns the following error message:

```
{
 "error": {
  "code": 503,
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "message": "Internal Server Error",
    "reason": "backendError"
   }
  ],
  "message": "Internal Server Error"
 }
}
```

There are 4 APIs created in the endpoints-frameworks-v2/echo sample. I get the same error message when I go to the API explorer and try to test the first 3 APIs. The last API get_user_email works as expected after after I authorise and execute it.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Have you tried executing the first 3 methods without OAuth? Those methods in the sample don't have any OAuth configuration (scopes, audiences, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It turned out to be a validation error though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a valadation error with what I was entering:

```
ValidationError: Expected type <type 'unicode'> for field content, found (None, None) (type <type 'tuple'>)
```

After I put in the expected type there was no issues.